# Разрешение SKScene. Соотношение сторон. SKCameraNode

Tags: ios, swift, разработка-игр, spritekit

Хотелось бы немного поговорить о том, как определить какие параметры и настройки выставлять для SKScene и SKCameraNode.

Пример. Я хочу создать игру. В игре присутствуют линейные уровни (на подобии Марио, ходишь влево и вправо). Я создал SKScene со следующим разрешением (y: 2048, т.е. самое большое разрешение среди устройств Apple по высоте и x: равен значению, которое соответствует размеру уровню). Также я создал SKCameraNode, который прикреплен к персонажу и движется вслед за ним.
Первая проблема, с которой я столкнулся это соотношение сторон. Т.к. различные девайсы Apple имеют различные форматы дисплеев, то, соответственно, игра везде отображается по разному. К примеру, на iPad картинка по высоте влезает полностью, а на iPhone пропадает верхняя и нижняя часть (формат landscape).

В голову пришла идея использовать в данной ситуации switch, тобеж:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 2436:
                print("iPhone X")
                cameraNode.yScale = (подгоняем значение под каждое устройство, к примеру 1.2)
            default:
                print("another iPhone")
```

И так мы прописываем в списке различные устройства, меняя параметр по оси Y.

В итоге, так получается, что при включении приложения на различных устройствах, игрок полностью видит игровую область.

Но я столкнулся с парой проблем.

1. Как бы я мог вместо того, чтобы прописывать каждое устройство, прописать настройки всего один раз? Проблема в том, что рано или поздно выходят новые устройства и придется тратить много времени на то, чтобы изменить параметры каждой игровой сцены, да и какое-то устройство можно из-за банальной невнимательности не внести в список и так получится, что когда игрок включит игру, его будет ждать не очень приятный сюрприз...
2. Я заметил, что в связи с тем, что параметр xScale остается не измененным, то картинка становится немного растянутой, чего тоже быть не должно.

В общем, если говорить коротко, то я хотел бы настроить камеру таким образом, чтобы она отдалялась от моего персонажа до тех пор, пока не упрется в края сцены. Тобеж игрок должен видеть сцену по оси Y полностью. Т.к. уровень большой, то по оси X сколько влезет в экран, столько влезет. Также, хотелось бы сделать какой нибудь защитный механизм, чтобы не получилось так, что игрок видит полностью всю сцену + черные полосы сверху и снизу.

В моем понимании, надо настроить камеру таким образом, чтобы у нее было определенное соотношение сторон и чтобы она не меняла это соотношение при изменении дальности от персонажа игры. Но не знаю как это можно реализовать.

Буду признателен, если Вы подскажите, как можно определить какой размер SKScene требуется выставить и почему? Как правильно настроить камеру? У меня получается найти материал касательно того, как настроить камеру или сцену, ну а вот на что опираться, чтобы выставить правильные параметры (я про то, как понять какое разрешение нужно и т.д.) у меня найти не получается.

Так как я не являюсь профессиональным программистом, объясните, пожалуйста, дураку на пальцах...

Для меня это, наверное, основная проблема в разработке...

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете выставить одно разрешение экрана, например 2048х1536 и scaleMode в aspectFill. Таким образом на всех устройствах будет одно и то же изображение, но оно будет обрезаться в зависимости от устройства. Используйте для игры область, которая будет видна на всех устройствах, а обрезаемую часть отведите под фон:

   class GameScene: SKScene {
   }

   ```
    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
   ```
2. Поищите книгу 2D Apple Games by Tutorials Beginning 2D iOS, tvOS, macOS & watchOS Game Development with Swift. В ней пошагово объясняется, как настроить сцену и камеру.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!
В принципе, я так и делаю, как Вы описали выше. Просто на данный момент мне не совсем ясно, как можно правильно настроить камеру, чтобы на каждом устройстве сцена отображалась так, как надо.

Буду изучать предложенный Вами материал.

Еще раз спасибо!